# Lazy loading crashes with "get_Info" not implemented under EF Core 3

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, lazy-loading, ef-core-3.0

I followed [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#lazy-loading) telling me that since version 2.1, I can do the following.

```
services.AddDbContext<Context>(c => c
  .UseLazyLoadingProxies()
  .UseSqlServer(...));
```

It doesn't work throwing the exception below. Commenting out the `UseLazyLoadingProxies` part makes it function properly, it's the laziness that's to blame).

> System.TypeLoadException
>     HResult=0x80131522
>     Message=Method 'get_Info' in type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Infrastructure.Internal.SqlServerOptionsExtension' from assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' does not have an implementation.
>     Source=Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer

I've installed the latest *Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Proxies* version.

```
Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Proxies -Version 3.0.0-preview7.19362.6
```

When I googled, there was some info on lazy loading not being implemented in EF Core but I assumed that was in 1.x or simply incorrectly described.

What a I missing?

If it's not implemented, I wonder how on Earth I'm supposed to stop circular references when emitting an object with children on my WebAPI but that's another story. Googling that led me to using lazies, namely.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to use the preview version? Is it an option to use 2.x?

Comment: @mjwills Well, the main reason for using preview version is that there's no final version available yet.

Comment: Preview versions are unstable and many things might not work. Wait to official release, I'm pretty sure this will work as it used to in the latest stable 2.x

Comment: @mjwills Oh, I just realized what you mean. Well, I want to be the first man to the ball. You know, being able to say been-there-done-that when it's released for real. But are you saying that it would work in e.g. Core 2.2? That it has been removed in Core 3.0?

Comment: Yes, it works in 2.x. And probably doesn't work temporarily in 3.0 preview (they are reimplementing the query processing part of the framework).